# last line of an R function prevent the plotting

Tags: r, function, class, attributes, r-s4

I'm really wondering why when I keep the last line (`sigma`) in my function `foo1` my `plot` call stops working BUT when I delete the last line in `foo2` the `plot` call works fine?!

*Note:* My understanding is that plot should show anywhere in the function like:

`foo3 <- function(x = 1:3){; plot(x); return(x); }; foo3()`

I need to keep the last line but I also need to plot, is this fixable?

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

h <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/h.csv')
h$year <- as.factor(h$year)
m <- lmer(scale~ year*group + (1|stid), data = h)

foo1 <- function(fit, plot = T){

  vc <- VarCorr(fit)
  f  <- as.formula(bquote(pairwise ~ .(terms(fit)[[3]])))
  ems <- emmeans(fit, f, infer = c(T, T))

  if(plot) plot(ems)

  ## Why having this line prevents plotting?
  sigma <- sqrt(sum(as.numeric(c(attr(vc[[1]], "stddev"), attr(vc, "sc")))^2)) 
}

###### EXAMPLE: Will NOT plot !!! 
foo1(m, plot = T)
```

But simply delete the last line of `foo1` and plot works fine!

```
foo2 <- function(fit, plot = T){

  f <- as.formula(bquote(pairwise ~ .(terms(fit)[[3]])))   
  ems <- emmeans(fit, f, infer = c(T, T))

  if(plot) plot(ems)
}

###### EXAMPLE: NOW plots fine !!!
foo2(m, plot = T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying cause for the unexpected behavior is that `emmeans` uses `ggplot2` as plotting method. You may examine the code of function `emmeans:::.plot.srg`. This is why you can store the plot in an object (`p`) and `print` it:

```
foo1 <- function(fit, plot=TRUE) {
  vc <- VarCorr(fit)
  f <- as.formula(bquote(pairwise ~ .(terms(fit)[[3]])))
  ems <- emmeans(fit, f, infer=c(TRUE, TRUE))
  sigma <- sqrt(sum(as.numeric(c(attr(vc[[1]], "stddev"), attr(vc, "sc")))^2))
  p <- plot(ems)
  if(plot) print(p)
  return(sigma)
}

foo1(m, plot=TRUE)  ## plots
# [1] 126.6106
```

Intuitively we expect the behavior like in your `foo3 <- function(x = 1:3){; plot(x); return(x); }; foo3()` example:

```
foo2 <- function(x, plot=TRUE) {
  y <- seq_len(x)^2
  if(plot) plot(seq_len(x), y)
  return(y)
}
foo2(20)  ## plots
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100 121 144 169
# [14] 196 225 256 289 324 361 400
```

But this works differently, when one uses `ggplot`. When we don't store the `"ggplot"` object, a following line will "overwrite" the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
foo3a <- function(x, plot=TRUE) {
  y <- seq_len(x)^2
  if(plot) ggplot(mapping=aes(seq_len(x), y)) + geom_point()
  return(y)  ## try to comment/un-comment this line
}
foo3a(20)  ## won't plot, just output of y (depending on `return`)
```

Therefore we have to actually `print` the `"ggplot"` object (I show this by storing the plot in `p` in function `foo3b`), if it's not the last line of the function.

```
foo3b <- function(x, plot=TRUE) {
  y <- seq_len(x)^2
  p <- ggplot(mapping=aes(seq_len(x), y)) + geom_point()
  if(plot) print(p)
  return(y)  ## try to comment/un-comment this line (works in both cases)
}
foo3b(20)  ## plots
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100 121 144 169
# [14] 196 225 256 289 324 361 400
```

Note that the use of `return` also is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that makes sense because in `foo2` `plot` is the last command in the function and it returns that whereas that is not the case in `foo1`.

A simple way if you want to `plot` and then do some additional calculation is to `print` it in the function.

```
foo1 <- function(fit, plot = T){

   vc <- VarCorr(fit)
   f <- as.formula(bquote(pairwise ~ .(terms(fit)[[3]])))

   ems <- emmeans(fit, f, infer = c(T, T))
   if(plot) print(plot(ems))
   sigma <- sqrt(sum(as.numeric(c(attr(vc[[1]], "stddev"), attr(vc, "sc")))^2)) 
}
```

then if you run `foo1`

```
x <- foo1(m, plot = T)
x
#[1] 126.61
```

it returns `sigma` value from the function and since we are using `print` it `plots` it as well.

Comment: But I'm sure plot doesn't need to be the last part to be shown!!!

Comment: Yes, if you check my function `foo1` it is not the last line of the function.

Comment: What is this then: `foo3 <- function(x = 1:3){;
  
  plot(x);
  return(x);
};

foo3()`

Comment: I think this is related to the `s4` used with the plot function for the package used in my specific case!

Comment: Ok..that's interesting. I am not sure what's happening there. I was under the impression that if your plot is not the last line in your function you need to explicitly print it for it to display.